# What is a sequence in python when passed to the join function?

Tags: python

Heyo

I'm learning Python and I came across this example:

`''.join(str(e) for e in blank)`

which returns:

`'sadfsdfsd_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ '`

I read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) and that example makes sense

So the code `str(e) for e in blank` is the sequence that is passed to the `join` method. But why doesn't it run independently?

```
str(e) for e in blank
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    str(e) for e in blank
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

blank btw is = `['text', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ', '_ ']`

Comment: `(str(e) for e in blank)` is a generator expression. It creates a generator object, which is an iterable, but not a sequence. TutorialsPoint is not... the best resource. Note, if you check the current docs of Python, the argument is named `iterable`, so it takes *any* iterable, not just sequences (which are things like `list`, `tuple`, `str`, `bytes`, and `range` objects). Sequences are objects that have have a `__len__` and are indexable from `0-(len(sequence)-1)`

Comment: Why doesn't the sequence generator work by itself?

Comment: There is no "sequence generator". You have a *generator expression* without parentheses, which are required *with the exception* of when you pass it as a single argument. You can use `(str(e) for e in blank)` as a valid generator expression.